# Behavior of read() and readlines() in Python

Tags: python, file-read

A functionality for writing automatically into a markdown file with Python has a bizarre behavior that I don't understand, so I'm trying to write it anew with tests. (I'm using the latest version of Python.)

I have the following code, super simple, which is the very beginning of the file writing :

```py
def add_new_line(file : str):
    with open(file, 'r') as fr:
        file_content = fr.read()
    
        with open(file, 'a+') as fw:
            if file_content != "" and not file_content.endswith("  \n"):
                fw.write("  \n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("markdown_test.md", 'a+') as fw:
        fw.write("TEST")

    add_new_line("markdown_test.md")

    with open("markdown_test.md", 'r') as fr:
        lines = fr.read()
```

Most of this code is here for me to try to understand something :
I'm writing the first line "TEST" in a file, and then enter the function in which I'm checking if it ends with "  \n", in which case markdown will put new content on a new line.
When I enter my function, open my file et read it, my debugger informs me that `fr.readlines()` actually reads "TEST". On the other hand, the line "file_content = fr.read()" is always equal to an empty string, therefore not adding the necessary characters at the end of the line.

Going out of that function, I try to read the file again, for a double check, and once again, `fr.read()` returns an empty string even though it should read "TEST".

I found this behavior while checking in a test if `fr.read().endswith('  \n')` was true. It was, but the test always failed, so I wanted to investigate further.

Could someone enlighten me on what's happening here ?

Thank you for your attention !

Comment: Code as shown, but with `print(repr(lines))` added in the `with` after `lines = fr.read()` prints `'TEST  \n'`.  After another run prints `'TEST  \nTEST  \n'`, etc.

Comment: You talk about `fr.readlines()` in the text, but that expression does not actually appear in your code.  So is that something you're doing yourself, in the debugger?  Keep in mind that this will change the current position of the file, which may affect subsequent code.  In particular, if you do this just before `fr.read()`, that expression will return an empty string because the file is already positioned at the end.

Comment: @jasonharper : Oh that's what I wasn't paying attention. I had the expression in my debugger `fr.readlines()` : I must have wrote it to check what it was doing, because I wasn't sure it didn't strip the line of unnecessary spaces, which it isn't. The code worked as I thought it should once I removed it. Thank you !